# NetworkExtension to monitor WiFi network changes even when app not running

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, wifi, networkextension

I wish to be able to prompt the user with contextual local notification depending of his current wifi network.
To do so I would need to monitor network change/ wifi connection.

Doing that while the app is running does not seems difficult, but I'm trying to think of a way that could always be reliable, even if app is in background or killed.
I was thinking of using a `NetworkExtension`, and more precisely a `NEHotspotHelper`.

Has anyone any insight on this to know if it's doable/good/bad? I can't find anything about it on google.

The most promising thing is [`NWPathMonitor`](https://medium.com/@rwbutler/nwpathmonitor-the-new-reachability-de101a5a8835), but is using that in a network extension the way to have it always running?

Comment: Hey, Did you get any solution? I am also trying to implement same thing, I want to know network/wifi changes while app is killed (Not in background )

Comment: No idea, that was a while ago I'm affraid :)

Comment: Hey, @indrajit did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @ParagPawar No, I did not. I did not explore it much.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, NWPathMonitor is the right way to monitor the network (see my POC: https://github.com/federicocappelli/NetworkPathMonitor) and it's battle-tested in a network extension (NSDNSProxyprovider in my case).
From the network extension you can easily send local notifications.

Comment: Thanks will have a look

Comment: @Kappe How to know wifi name and status while the app is killed ?

Comment: @indrajit I don't think you can using NWPathMonitor

Comment: @Kappe Any idea? I stopped the exploration.